# Enforce to avoid circular dependency

Tags: java, spring, interface, circular-dependency

Is there a way to enforce the implementations (all POJOs) of an interface to not have any circular dependency ?

or how to check for any circular dependencies in the code while, say, server startup

or any tool which can detect circular dependencies

Comment: Is it a question about Java or Spring injection?

Comment: I’m Using spring in the project so in case it has something out of the box.. but I’m dealing with pojo right now.. I want to enforce pojo will not have circular dependency.

Comment: could be useful http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

To solve spring bean circular dependencies,  though there are different solutions(link given by Mara has some interesting workarounds), i normally use @Lazy annotations,

But to find circular dependencies,   intellij has some features to see bean diagrams in an application. I am sure you will find many other tools as well.

I use intellij for a lot of its features, and it has some features for your requirement :

For Spring bean dependencies: module dependency diagram for spring dependencies( click on the tiny square green symbol one left side of the annotation)

For java dependencies :   on main toolbar -> Analyze -> analyze cyclic dependencies..